# handle nginx with multiple php version folder wise

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I have a Laravel Project setup with docker. The project is working fine but I got some old PHP core codes running in one of the folders. I have set up two PHP versions in docker :

```bash
services:
  nginx:
    # will build ./nginx/Dockerfile
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
#      - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel

  php56:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./config/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/public/php56
    #      - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

As you can see php56 is running with PHP 5.6 and php service is running php 8.1. Let me add the dockerfile as well.

DockerFile for 8.1

```bash
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine3.14

ENV WORK_DIR=/var/www/html
WORKDIR ${WORK_DIR}

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql soap bcmath zip

ADD . /var/www
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

DockerFile for 5.6

```bash
FROM php:5.6-fpm-alpine

ENV WORK_DIR=/var/www/html
WORKDIR ${WORK_DIR}

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql soap bcmath zip
```

As the php56 lies in Laravel public path, we need to run that specific folder with a different PHP version. Let me add the nginx.conf file as well.

```bash
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ^~ /php56 {
        root /var/www/html/public/php56;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /php56/index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass php56:9001;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }
    }

      location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass php:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }

    location ~ /\.ht {
         deny all;
    }
}
```

This is my whole setup and the Laravel is working fine but the php56 folder is not working. Any help would be great. Thank you